# Need to switch my app to background after a phone restart or power on

Tags: android, android-intent

I need my android app to be in background mode after a phone restart/power on.

Currently I am using the following code, so that my app successfully gets launched after a phone restart/power on.

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<receiver android:enabled="true" android:name="my_package.BootUpReceiver" android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**BootUpReceiver.java:**

```
public class BootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    private static SharedPreferences aSharedSettings;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        aSharedSettings = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean isUserLoggedIn = aSharedSettings.getBoolean(Key.AUTHENTICATED, false); 
        if(isUserLoggedIn) 
        {
            Intent aServiceIntent = new Intent(context, MyHomeView.class);
                    aServiceIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            aServiceIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(aServiceIntent); 
        }
    }
}
```

As I said above, my app successfully gets launched after a phone restart/power on.

However, after the phone restart/power on, my app was in foreground mode. But I need my app to be in background mode.

Can anyone please say, how to make an app to be in background mode after a phone restart or power on.

I even tried by changing the intent category to

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
```

But no use in it. Can anyone please help me?

Thanks.

Comment: why do you need to be in background? Your app waits for some event?

Comment: Thanks for the response Leonidos. I need my app to be just running in background after the phone restart, so that users can select from the minimized app. Can you please say, what I have done wrong in the above code. Instead of foreground mode, my app needs to be in background after a restart. Once again thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion which Leonidos replied is correct.

However, Just a workaround for this:

In my BootUpReceiver, I had a seperate boolean flag for this! (Its a bad way. but just a workaround)

```
SharedPreferences.Editor aPrefEditor = aSharedSettings.edit();
aPrefEditor.putBoolean(Key.IS_DEVICE_RESTARTED, true);
aPrefEditor.commit();
```

In Oncreate method of MyHomeView:

```
boolean isDeviceRestarted = aSharedSettings.getBoolean(Key.IS_DEVICE_RESTARTED, false);
if(isDeviceRestarted)
{
    SharedPreferences.Editor aPrefEditor = aSharedSettings.edit();
    aPrefEditor.putBoolean(MamaBearKey.IS_DEVICE_RESTARTED, false);
    aPrefEditor.commit();
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> I need my app to be just running in background after the phone restart, so that users can select from the minimized app

I think your approach is wrong. All you are trying to do now is to add icon of your app to recent apps list. Your app won't run in background and I think you don't really want it. Am I right?

Recent apps list managed by android and IMHO forcing your app to be in recent apps list is not a very good idea. User will start you app when he wants from launcher or icon on his desktop.

Answer (score 1):

If your broadcast receiver is working fine and app is starting successfully then you can use the below code in your `MyHomeView` activity's `onCreate` method to go to the home screen.

> Trick is to click HOME button programmatically when app starts.

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);
```

you can pass some variable from the BroadcastReceiver to differentiate a normal request and BroadcastReceiver's request to make the above code conditional.

**But if you want to execute it always in background then it would be better to use [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).**

**It is recommended to change your code to the service to run it in background.**

Comment: Thanks CCMinds. I will change my code to service. But I have a doubt. Instead of having the above code in MyHomeView activity's onCreate method, I already tried the same code in my BroadcastReceiver (Now I have edited the code, please refer the edited code above). But its not working. Any help please..